# Can't update Apexcharts components value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, apexcharts

I am using **Apexchart** library in **Vue.js** to plot the data on scatterplots. I can **POST** my data using Axios. I can see the data coming to the browser by doing **console.log()** to view the data I receive. By using the **updateChart()** function, which is the Apexcharts property, I do the necessary operations on the incoming data. I cannot send the data to the data array. You can find the reference sample of Apexcharts [here](https://apexcharts.com/docs/vue-charts/).

Chart.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="grid ml">
    <div id="main">
      <h1 class="header ml">SEARCH VOLUME</h1>
      <apexcharts
        id="chart"
        height="300"
        type="bar"
        :options="chartOptions"
        :series="series"
      ></apexcharts>
      <button @click="updateChart">Update!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueApexCharts from "vue-apexcharts";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          id: "vuechart-example",
        },
        colors: ["#9999CC"],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false,
          style: {
            colors: ["#9999CC"],
          },
        },
        noData: {
          text: "Loading...",
        },
        title: {
          text: "lorem ipsum dolar sit amet",
          align: "left",
          margin: 10,
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
          floating: false,
          style: {
            fontSize: "14px",
            fontWeight: "regular",
            fontFamily: "Barlow, sans-serif",
            color: "#6B6B99",
          },
        },
        xaxis: {
          labels: {
            style: {
              colors: "#6B6B99",
              fontSize: "12px",
              fontFamily: "Barlow, sans-serif",
              fontWeight: 400,
              cssClass: "apexcharts-xaxis-label",
            },
          },
          categories: [
            "JAN",
            "FEB",
            "MAR",
            "APR",
            "MAY",
            "JUN",
            "JUL",
            "AUG",
            "SEP",
            "OCT",
            "NOV",
            "DEC",
          ],
        },
        yaxis: {
          labels: {
            style: {
              colors: "#6B6B99",
              fontSize: "12px",
              fontFamily: "Barlow, sans-serif",
              fontWeight: 400,
              cssClass: "apexcharts-xaxis-label",
            },
          },
        },
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "Company",
          data: [1,2,3,4],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateChart() {
      axios
        .post("http://APIURL", {
          country: "tr",
          lang: "tr",
          keyword: "ankara",
        })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          this.series = [
            {
              data: data,
            },
          ];

          // this.series = data;
          console.log("DATAAA", data);
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    },
  },
  components: {
    apexcharts: VueApexCharts,
  },
  beforeMount() {},
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#chart {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 760px;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.ml {
  font-size: 24px;
}

#main {
  width: 1142px;
  height: 566px;
}
</style>
```

Browser console screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1D2A.png)

The part where I can't send the data to the array

```js
series: [
        {
          name: "Company",
          data: [1,2,3,4],
        },
      ],
```

Comment: Does it work if you change your `updateChart` to set `data` to a simple array like `[5,6,7,8]`?

Comment: @Dan It's okay if the data is organized as in the example [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/50z5wrmp6k), but I can't update the data received from the server axios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the doc examples, the data is an array of values, but your api is returning an array of objects.  Try changing your `updateChart` method to use only values by mapping the api array to just its `volume` values:

```
.then(({ data }) => {
  this.series = [
    {
      data: data.map(o => o.volume),
    },
  ];
})
```

Comment: I get this error when I add the code and run it.
This dependency was not found:

* core-js/modules/es.array.map.js in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Chart.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

Comment: Run npm install --save core-js/modules/es.array.map.js

Error is a npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "core-js/modules/es.array.map.js" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/alpercun/.npm/_logs/2021-01-27T15_04_34_123Z-debug.log

Comment: Maybe you have a problematic Vue CLI install because your compiler should know what `map` is...

Answer (score 1):

@Dan By improving the method you show, I can plot the data into the chart.

```js
.then(({ data }) => {
     console.log(typeof data);
     this.series = [...this.series, { data: data.map((o) => o.volume) }];
   })
.catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Comment: Hm the only difference seems to be prepending the existing series in the data array which doesn't explain why you got a `map` error the first time   Anyway, glad you got it working